# Navigation in Angular is being triggered multiple times, at first gets successfully routed and then gets redirected to wrong url

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to navigate the user from localhost:4200/C/D/E to localhost:4200/A/12345/B when a link is clicked. But the user gets redirected to just localhost:4200/A at the end of navigation.

I use router.navigate and it returns true after the first trigger. But the navigation gets triggered again, and then it is redirected to the wrong URL. I tried tracing the navigation, by setting `enableTracing: true`. `NavigationEnd` event was triggered two times. After first `urlAfterRedirects` was correct localhost:4200/A/12345/B. After second `urlAfterRedirects` was wrong localhost:4200/A.

```
navigateToNewScreen() {
    this.router.navigate(['A', '12345', 'B']).then(navigated => {
      console.log('navigation success? :', navigated); // this is true after the first NavigationEnd event
      if (navigated) {
        //do something
      }
    });
  }
```

I expect that either the `NavigationEnd` event gets triggered only once. Or even if gets triggered multiple times, the expected `urlAfterRedirects` does not change. Any help with this issue is welcome.

**Edit:**

CRoutingModule (from):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const path = 'app/main/features/C';
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'D',
    loadChildren: `${path}/D/D.module#DModule`
  },
  {
    path: 'P',
    loadChildren: `${path}/P/P.module#PModule`
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'D' }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forChild(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class CRoutingModule {
}
```

ARoutingModule (to):

```
import {  NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const path = 'app/main/features/A';
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':id',
    component: BComponent,
    children: [   
      {
        path: 'Y',
        loadChildren: `${path}/Y/Y.module#YModule`
      },    
      {
        path: 'B',
        loadChildren: `${path}/B/B.module#BModule`
      },      
      { path: '**', redirectTo: 'Y' }
    ]
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ARoutingModule { }
```

MainRoutingModule

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'A',
        loadChildren: 'app/main/features/A/A.module#AModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'C',
        loadChildren: 'app/main/features/C/C.module#CModule'
      },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: 'A' }
    ]
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forChild(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class MainRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: try: this.router.navigate(['/','A', '12345', 'B'])

Comment: @tano, tried just now. did not work :(

Comment: can you share the routing rules?

Comment: @tano, edited the question with the routing rules for both modules.

Comment: i should see the main routing rules too

Comment: hi @tano, updated with main routing rules

Comment: Can you put your code on Stackblitz, to understand the issue more clearly.

Comment: it seems its ok. The root cause should be found in BModule routing. After redirection to it, it forwards to 'A'. the main routing has the rule  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'A' } this tries to forward to A, but A has no rule for empty path, but to redirect to ''. In submodules, there's no need to redirect to '' since it is handled in main routing. And in main routing since you redirect to A in case no valid route found, the outer redirection to '' is meaningless. I wouldn't redirect to A, since it redirects to route path which redirects to A.